# Netgear DGN3500 wireless modem router 300mpbs speeds possible using wi fi security

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Netgear DGN3500 wireless modem router  stating that I can get 300mpbs speeds over WI FI. But I can only get this on an unsecured set up, I cannot get this if I enable the security settings, WPA etc... Once I enable the security I only get 54mpbs.

How can I get up to 300mpbs with a secured wifi networ

Comment: The clients you are connecting to it are set to use 802.11N right, and not 802.11G? If the NIC in your computer/client can only support 802.11G (54Mbps speed) then it doesn't matter if the router can support faster speeds - you only transfer as fast as the client can handle.

Answer (score 0):

First, I found this...

> Most 802.11n products will knock your throughput down by up to 80% if you use WEP or WPA/TKIP security. The reason is that the 802.11n spec states that the high throughput rates (link rates above 54 Mbps) can't be enabled if either of those outdated security methods are used.

Meaning...

> Use WPA2/AES and Enable WMM. WMM must be enabled in order to get link rates higher than 54 Mbps.

Dug that up here at [SmallNetBuilder](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30664-5-ways-to-fix-slow-80211n-speed).

So, switch to WPA2 and enable WMM.  That should kick your speeds back up between the N clients and the N router.